# Sum values from another table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an `users` table and `amount` table.
The `users` table has following columns.

```
name id
A      1
B      2
C      3
D      4
```

The `amount` table has following columns.

```
userId  amount id
1      10      1
1      20      2
1      10      3
2      12      4
```

I need a sql which sums all the users amount from the `amount` table

Final output would be

```
name id    totalAmount
A      1    30
B      2    12
C      3    0
D      4    0
```

I have tried using but does not work. Kindly help

```
let searchQuery = `SELECT u.id, u.name, (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0) from amount WHERE amount.userId = u.id) as totalAmount, FROM users u LEFT JOIN amount amt on u.id = amt.userId WHERE`;
```

Comment: Could you please format your expected output? It's not clear if you want it in one or many rows.

Comment: Your query has some typos in it,  you're missing a comma after u.name and you have 'WHERE' with no conditions after it.  Does it run at all? If it does run, what's wrong with the results it gives you?

Comment: @JeffUK It does run... but it splits the result number of times the `amount` table has that `userId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax for correlated subquery version

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, (SELECT coalesce(SUM(a.amount), 0) 
                      FROM amount a
                      WHERE a.userId = u.id) as totalAmount
FROM users u
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using standard sql aggregation

```
select 
  u.name,
  u.id,
  sum(a.amount) as totalAmount
from users u
  left join amount a
    on a.userId = u.id
group by u.name, u.id
```

The `left join` is just to include those users whitout amounts, which will have a 0 as `totalAmount`

Comment: ohhh so I have to group it... Is it necessary no other option?

Comment: It's the usual way to do it, but you have the @Serg answer with another way